# How to make "likes" to comments (responses)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are tables of users. And users have to mark out those comments of other users which answer is pleasant to them. How to make "likes" to comments (responses)?

**Models.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.text %></td>
        <td><%= comment.user.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Comment: comment has_many :likes. user has_many :likes. user has_many :comments, through: :likes.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need an another model - `Like`.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
end
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commend
end
```

Controller:

```
def like
  Like. find_or_create_by_user_id_and_comment_id(current_user.id, params[:commend_id])
end
```

Something like this. You'll also have to take care of validation and so on.